# Pass Selected Data from one page to other page in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am using form to pass the data from one page to other page.If i click the apply button will go to other page, i want to display the corresponding title of the career(i.e Java Developer) in the next page.I tried to achieve this with the help of javascript.

career.html:

```
    <form action="job portal.html" method="get" target="_blank">
                    <div class="section-header text-center wow zoomIn">
                        <h2>Current Oppournities</h2>

                    </div><br /><br />

                    <div class="row">


                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="box wow fadeInLeft">

                                <h4 class="title" id="career-title" name="career-title"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-java"></i>&nbsp;<b>Java Developer</b></a></h4>
                                <hr />
                                <div class="carrer-opt">
                                    <h5 name="test">Software Developer</h5>

                                    <p>

                                        Should have join immediate joiner .
                                    </p>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 cta-btn-container">
                                    <input type="submit" id="apply"  value="Apply Now" onClick="testJS()" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

</form>
```

js:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        function testJS() {
            var b = document.getElementById('career-title').value,
                url = 'job portal.html?career-title=' + encodeURIComponent(b);

            document.location.href = url;
        }
    </script>
```

job portal.html:

```
 <h1 id="here" style="color:black"></h1>
```

js:

```
  <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var url = document.location.href,
                params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
                data = {}, tmp;
            for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
                tmp = params[i].split('=');
                data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
            }
            document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.career-title;
        }
    </script>
```

How to acheive this.Anyone please help.

Comment: check this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: But I want to display the title depending upon the selected value

Comment: In line `document.getElementById('career-title').value` return `undefined` therefore changes `document.querySelector('#career-title b').innerHTML` to obtain the career title

Comment: It's also not return any value.

Comment: check this - https://jsfiddle.net/2q73nwtr/13/

Comment: It return the value but not displayed in another page.

Comment: why you just use `Local Storage` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTML5 local storage for these kind of problems.
here is solution for your problem.

```
<script>
    function testJS() {
        var b = document.getElementById('career-title').value;
        var titleText = localStorage.setItem('title', b);
        var url = 'job portal.html';

        document.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

after setting title value get value by referencing id 'title' in your prtal.html script and set value for the element.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var valueText = localStorage.getItem('title');
        document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = valueText;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It displayed Undefined in job portal.html page

Comment: It's Work with the small change instead of document.getElementById('career-title').value change to document.querySelector('#career-title b').innerHTML

Comment: It's store only one value in localstorage.how to set and get multiple values

Comment: for multiple values you can create object and then retrieve that object wherever you want to use.